# CComboBoxEx problems with different DPI, height calculation

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, combobox, dpi

I want to add a CComboBoxEx on my form, but I have to align it with other controls and make  it the same height.

The problem is that I can't find which is the correct way to get the height of this control.

If I set the window rectangle, that affects the drop down listbox. If I force it to be some fixed size, and the content inside the combo is higher, the control gets clipped at the bottom.

Is there a way to calculate how big the ComboBoxEx will be, based on image and current DPI settings? So that I could at least expand the other controls if I cannot adjust the internal padding of the control. MSDN doesn't touch the sizing issues at all as far as I've looked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComboBoxes set the height of the control automatically, and as you've discovered, trying to set your own height actually affects the height of the drop-down list.

To get the real height of the control (so you can resize your other controls) you can use GetWindowRect:

```
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(hWndCombo, &rc);
int iComboHeight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
```

I don't know of a good way to change the height of the Combo control itself, and frankly I don't believe it's possible at least without lots of subclassing. I have implemented my own combo-style control because of this.

Although it probably won't help, you may also like to have a look at the GetComboBoxInfo() function to see if that provides any useful information.